# How to handle errors when processing different monads?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Monad is used to handle error gracefully, but when chain Task monads after Nothing, it will complain fork(which supposed provided by Task) is not there. See the code below (using falktale):

```
it.only('handle different monads', done => {
    const getUserById = id => new Task((reject, result) => setTimeout(
        ()=>result({ userName: 'ron' })
        , 0
    ))

    const getUser = pipe(
        Maybe.fromNullable,
        chain(getUserById)
    )

    expect(getUser(null).fork( // complains here: getUser(...).fork is not a function
        ()=>done(),
        x=> done('should not be triggered')
    ))
})
```

The reason cause the unexpected result is because chain(...) actually running Nothing.map which will return Nothing without fork function.

Comment: Yes, you will need to convert the `Maybe` into a `Task`.

Comment: make sense. But if it is Nothing, seems it will always return Nothing, no matter going with map, chain or ...

Comment: Yes, none of the Functor/Applicative/Monad methods does anything for type conversion. You need to do it manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem via using cata/fold. Also because the falktale Maybe doesn't support fold, so have to use fantasy option, and also need to nature transform maybe to option. The below is the passed unit test:

```
const Maybe = require('data.maybe')
const Either = require('data.either')

const Task = require('data.task')
const {Some, None} = require('fantasy-options')
const {fold} = require('pointfree-fantasy')
const {chain, liftM2} = require('control.monads')
import {pipe, length, curry, prop, equals, tap} from 'ramda'
import {expect} from 'chai'

it.only('handle different monads', done => {

    const getUserById = id => new Task((reject, result) => setTimeout(
        () => result({ userName: 'ron' })
        , 0
    ))

    const maybeToOption = m => m.cata({Just: Some, Nothing: ()=> None})

    const getUser = pipe(
        Maybe.fromNullable,
        maybeToOption,
        fold(chain(getUserById), ()=>new Task(rej=>rej()))
    )

    expect(getUser(null)['fork'](
        () => done(),
        x => done('should not be triggered')
    ))
})
```

Also check the video: https://youtu.be/oZ6C9h49bu8, it explained the whole thing deeply.